# How to unit test 'Azure AD and OpenID Connect' code in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, azure-active-directory, owin, openid-connect

Hi I am using the Azure AD and OpenID Connect to authenticate users to my app. I have used the traditional code as mentioned in azure docs.

> Startup.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Function to set the authentication configurtion
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">Owin properties</param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

> Startup.Auth.cs

```
private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
                ClientId = "ClientId",
                Authority = "Authority",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "PostLogoutRedirectUri"
            });
    }
```

> AccountController.cs

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public void SignIn()
    {
        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties {RedirectUri = "/"},
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to signout the session user from the application
    /// </summary>
    public void SignOut()
    {
        if (Request.Url == null) {
            return;
        }
        string callbackUrl = Url.Action("SignOutCallback", "Account", null, Request.Url.Scheme);

        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties {RedirectUri = callbackUrl},
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to redirect the user to home screen.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Redirects to home screen if authentication still exists</returns>
    public ActionResult SignOutCallback()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Not sure how to start unit testing the above code. I didn't find much useful resources on this topic, will **appreciate** any leads.

Answer (score 1):

@coder89

Unit testing this is in my view not an option. All of the classes which are part of the framework has already been unit tested. 
From your question it seems to me what you are looking at is some sort of integration test. As you have the entire pipeline running here you are likely looking at UI testing using something like [Selenium](https://docs.seleniumhq.org) to do the trick. [Browserstack](https://browserstack.com) is widely used for such kind of testing.